# Why use the service command in linux?

Tags: linux, service

What is the difference between

```
service apache2 restart
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

So basically why is the service command recommended compared to directly invoking the appropriate command?

Comment: It may depend upon your actual Linux distribution, but on some both have the same effect.

Comment: This would be a better fit on http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ or maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/ as it's not a programming question.

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu, the question is answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2075/whats-the-difference-between-service-and-etc-init-d See also this on Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/questions/85621/to-restart-a-service-e-g-httpd-should-i-use-etc-init-d-httpd-restart-or-sbi

Comment: @Jonik thanks that answers my question. I dont think I can close my question but if you put your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept your answer

Answer (score 7):

The `service` command runs the init scripts in a predictable environment:

> service runs a System V init script in as predictable environment as possible, removing most environment variables and with current working directory set to /.

from: http://linux.die.net/man/8/service